# How can I expose kubernetes services running within docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

What I want to do is run kubernetes within docker and expose the kubernetes services externally. I followed the [docs](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.html) on getting kubernetes running within docker.  As long as I connect from the `localhost`, I can access my services. However, connecting from a different computer doesn't work.  If I spin up a docker image directly, then I can access it.  Only things running within kubernetes aren't exposed.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you're running with `--net=host`, you're using the host's network stack, which is equivalent to running the service directly on the host. If that doesn't work, looks like there's something else blocking access?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your nodes have externally reachable IP addresses.

Then create a service of type NodePort:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#type-nodeport

And direct traffic to nodes at the allocated port.